# Слишком мало FPS у 2D отрисовки DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx

Есть оконный Overlay DirectX, при отрисовки у меня FPS не поднимается выше 100, а иногда и скачет от 30 до 90, хотя я даже все вычисления сделал в отдельном потоке. Вот параметры: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём же может быть проблема?

Comment: может в коде отрисовки у Вас sleep + сложные вычисления. или ожидание пользовательского ввода.

Comment: KoVadim, да, у меня слип для потока в 1 МС, все вычисления я вынес в отдельный поток, таким образом, при отрисовки у меня идёт только обращение к нужным данным и сама отрисовка. Слип тут не играет значительной роли учитывая то, что FPS у меня сильно и нелогично скачет.

Comment: а Вам точно нужен слип? Более того, не все слипы одинаково хороши. И то, что Вы просите 1 мс, ещё не значит, что оно будет именно 1мс работать. Также, всегда в таких случаях нужно профилировать и смотреть, смотреть, смотреть.

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо, сейчас покопаюсь и посмотрю. Может быть проблема реально в этом.

Comment: Как показал профилировщик, dxDevice->Present занимает очень много времени

Comment: а в приведенном выше коде этого нет.

Comment: Ну там 5 строчек: 
dxDevice_->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
dxDevice_->BeginScene();
draw();
dxDevice_->EndScene();
dxDevice_->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);